# arm-none-eabi-gcc fails with ld: cannot find -lg: No such file or directory

Tags: macos, gcc, linker-errors

I've just installed ARM GCC 12.2.rel1 AArch32 bare-metal target (arm-none-eabi) on MacOS. The only manual configuration I have done is to add the bin path to my `.zshrc` Compiling anything with `-g` or `-debug` results in

```
/Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/12.2.rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lg: No such file or directory
```

Is something missing from the install?